# UserDefaults in cloud vs Core Data in cloud

Tags: swift, core-data, nsuserdefaults, icloud, icloud-drive

I'm trying to find the best way to store user settings (preferences) between devices. I have a big Core Data model which contains a lot of entities to store main info. To interact with this info, user has to choose some settings. So if I'd like to allow him not only see the up-to-date base on all his devices, I want him to interact with it the same way (example: one setting changed on iPhone will automatically be changed on an iPad which linked to the same Apple ID and has the same app).

What will you advice me to do? How to store preferences and please, tell me where to read about iCloud sync. I hope Apple did it not too difficult to implement.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For settings that are shared across devices, look into `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`. It's a lot like `NSUserDefaults` but it's shard over iCloud. Core Data is generally not a good choice for user settings, though of course it depends on what kind and amount of data make up your settings.